# how to use sendmsg() system call in server client program

Tags: linux, kernel, recvmsg, sendmsg

I'm going through sendmsg systemcall, i want to trigger this sendmsg systemcall using a server client programs and what to use ftrace to trace what functions are involved and understand the flow of sendmsg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the msgsnd() system call as follows. [Reference](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd)

syntax:

`int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);`

```
int ret = msgsnd(msq_id, &msg, sizeof(msg.data), 0);
    if(ret< 0){
        perror("msgsnd() failed");
        _exit(-1);
    }
// message is sent
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i wanted to invoke sendmsg() not msgsnd()